# How to replace RichText Content Control by PlainText Content Control

Tags: c#, openxml, contentcontrol

We've just discovered that Rich Text Content Controls does not allow line breaks.

We have several thousands of word document that are used as templates.
I need a way to programmatically replace each Rich Text content control whit a Plain Text one and allow line breaks.

There seems to be no attribute in the XML that denotes a Rich text content control from a plain text one.

Could I simply add :

```
<w:text w:multiLine="1"/>
```

To each content control or should I delete the old one and create a new one ?

**UPDATE 1** : according to [this post](http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/17/p/7137/162247.aspx) :

> There is a child element of the w:stdPr element that indicates the type of content control.
>   The default type of content control is Rich Text, so if this is the type of the content control you will not see this child element.
>
> If the content control type is plain text, there will be a child
>    element.

Comment: What a rich text control doesn't generally allow is content control data binding. Line breaks are fine, as are tables (provided its a block level control), nested content controls etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new child element of type **SdtContentText** is indeed the solution.

I'm using the [OpenXML Power Tools](http://powertools.codeplex.com/).

The following code is taken from [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/04/11/137383.aspx) :

```
public static class ContentControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> ContentControls(
        this OpenXmlPart part)
    {
        return part.RootElement
            .Descendants()
            .Where(e => e is SdtBlock || e is SdtRun);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> ContentControls(
        this WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        foreach (var cc in doc.MainDocumentPart.ContentControls())
            yield return cc;
    }
}
```

And then :

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
                 WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFile, true))
    {
        foreach (var cc in doc.ContentControls())
        {
            SdtProperties props = cc.Elements<SdtProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
            Tag tag = props.Elements<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
            SdtContentText text = props.Elements<SdtContentText>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (text == null)
            {
                text = new SdtContentText();
                text.MultiLine = new OnOffValue(true);
                cc.AppendChild<SdtContentText>(text);
            }
            if (tag != null)
                Console.WriteLine(tag.Val);
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
```